# Dependency injection for unit testing vs. class managing its own variables

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I have a class that is something like this (very simplified but this is the general idea. I'm not actually using the raw socket type):

```
class ConnectionBroker {

    private Socket socket;

    public ConnectionBroker(ConnectionDetails details) {
        socket = new Socket(details)
        //set socket paramaters
    }

    public sendOverConnection(String message) {
        //processing of message and internal queuing based on priority
        socket.send(message);
    }

    public shutdown() {
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

It would be valuable if I could unit test the class's functions by mocking the socket variable to check what is being sent over the socket. The standard way of doing this that I have seen is modifying the constructor to be

```
public ConnectionBroker(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
}
```

This would make unit testing a lot easier, however I have a number of issues with doing it this way:

- The socket should be maanged only by the `ConnectionBroker` class
- The fact that the `ConnectionBroker` class  uses sockets at all should be abstracted away from the calling class
- If the socket needs to be passed in then the calling code could possibly modify attributes on the socket which the the `ConnectionBroker` class is not aware of

What is the proper way of solving this? Am I thinking of something incorrectly?

Comment: non-public `ConnectionBroker(Socket socket)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if `ConnectionBroker(Socket socket)` is the standard way, it has its pros and cons as you pointed out.

Obviously the problematic bit of your code is the call to `new Socket(details)`, which hinders testing.

In an almost similar scenario I introduced a new dependency `SocketProvider` with a single method `getSocket()` that ends up creating the socket:

`public Socket getSocket() {
   return new Socket();`

This makes it trivial for unit tests to provide an implementation or subclass that returns a mock / stub / spy... E.g.

```
@Mock 
private Socket mockedSocket;
@Mock 
private SocketProvider mockedProvider;

// ...
conncectionBroker.setSocketProvider(mockedProvider);

// ...

when(mockedProvider.getSocket()).return(mockedSocket); // or a stub / spy / testSocket...
```

It also allows to provide different implementations for different environments and testing scenarios - which IMO makes it the nicer approach to the one that you suggested (where the creation logic lays within the responsibility of an individual test).

Comment: Thanks Jan, what would your implementation of ``SocketProvider`` look like? Is it a static class?

Comment: Well, it should the code that makes it hard to test `ConnectionBroker`... (Which is the actual creation of the socket with `new Socket()`)

Comment: @jangroth in the constructor if the Socket is beign passed then he would not be doing a new on it.  so this si the same as getting the socket passed in the constructor just a more annoying way of doing it.

Comment: I'm talking about this:  Not sure if ConnectionBroker(Socket socket) is the standard way, it has its pros and cons as you pointed out.

Obviously the problematic bit of your code is the call to new Socket(details), which hinders testing.

Comment: Well, you are right about it making little difference for a single unit test. However I ended up having 2 or 3 different implementations of the Provider to cater for different environment as well as different tests (e.g. integration tests). So I wouldn't exactly call it annoying from my perspective :)